# SQL backup "Operating System error 13", system.Io.error

Tags: sql-server, backup, virtualbox, hyper-v

I lately changed my virtual machine from a Virtual Box to Hyper-V because of better performance on Hyper-V. After I did this I cannot restore a database (2008R2 all environments, same version) from outside a test or production environment, and I could before. I request this error in my SQL log:

backupiorequest::reportioerror read failure on backup device. Operating system error 13 (failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason 15105)

I tried ofcause google, which tells me that Operating System error 13 is somekind of "permission failure". I tried to give the backup file full control for everyone, but seems not to make any difference.

I think it is a permission problem, im just stuck and dont know how to solve the problem, any suggestions?

I changed my virtual machine name from one thing to another, could it be the problem so my "rights" is right now assigned to oldName and not newName and if yes, where do I need to change those?

Comment: `SQL Server error 15105` is a hint of SQL Server not having enough permission to access the resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to look at the permission for the SQL database, it seems to be ok. Tried to move it back to the original server. Seems that something went in the transaction to the endpoint.

The SQL.bak. Tried to do it again got the same result. So something is going on when im transfer it to a shared drive and grabbing it from there :(

So the answer is that the header file is broken :(

Answer (score 0):

You can lookup error codes here, for example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx

As it states, error 13 (or 0x0D) is ERROR_INVALID_DATA, so chances are, your backup is corrupted.

You can try to copy it to different machine and restore there. Also, it wouldn't hurt to run `restore verifyonly` and `restore headeronly` against the backup.